# Rear wheel moving from side to side

Tags: rear-wheel

[image]

Rear wheel is moving from side to side anyone have any ideas what might be the problem thanks

Comment: It's said that a picture is worth a thousand words, but I'm at a loss determining the thousand words this image might be worth... The critical information that we would need to answer your question is: **What** does move? The tire/rim as the wheel rotates? The tire/rim when you push from the side? The *entire* wheel including the hub?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the link below. This question has been answered already and they do a pretty good job of explaining the possible issues/solutions.

[Rear bike wheel wobbling](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32247/my-rear-bike-wheel-is-wobbling-back-and-forth-when-i-ride)

Comment: Good find - the normal process is to mark this whole question as a duplicate of the other, which can be done with the [flag] link straight under the question.